# list of java mqtt brokers and its scalability in windows

Tags: java, android, windows, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to achieve push notifications in android.
I don't want to use GCM for some reasons and hence started working with MQTT. 
I am currently using Mosquitto MQTT broker.
I need to know the limit on number of clients connections that the Mosquitto broker can handle on windows?
I am in need of a Java MQTT Broker and found HiveMQ and Moquette. Is there any other?
HiveMQ allows only 25 simultaneously connected clients for free and hence i don't want to use that.
I need details regarding how to use Moquette and how scalable it is on Windows?

Thanks in Advance!
Expecting some quick and clear replies please..Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that HiveMQ is not restricted to 25 concurrent connections anymore if you don't want to purchase a full-fledged license. To try out if HiveMQ fits your scalability needs (do benchmarks for your own scenario to verify!), there is a pay-as-you-go licensing available: [HiveMQ PAYG](https://payg.hivemq.com)

Answer (score 0):

Mosquitto is currently limited to 1024 clients on Windows. This is down to using the BSD style networking API (and its associated limits in Windows) and will change at some point in the future. Don't hold your breath though!

Comment: Can you tell about Moquette MQTT broker and how scalable it is on windows of course?

Comment: If I could, I would have done. I don't know any performance details on Moquette I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your answer. Any suggestions on how to increase this limit?

Comment: Rewrite mosquitto to use Windows AIOCP. It's a big job. In practice it means using an event loop library like libuv. Still a huge job though.

Comment: If your question is whether mosquitto supports 1024 connections on Windows, see my answer above :) If Moquette, then see my comment above :)

Comment: Is Mosquitto available for 64 bit? I am currently using 32 bit binaries.

Comment: It should compile fine for 64 bit. It shouldn't really be necessary to be honest with a 1024 client limit, unless you're sending very large messages.